# Datatables header and body mislignment when using 'scrollX'

Tags: html, jquery, datatables

I'm very new with datatables plugin and when i load the data to display in the table with using `scrollX` the column header and body is misalignment.
[image]

And this is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <div id="contact_div" style="padding:10px;">
         <table class="table table-hover table-sm table-striped" id="contact_table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
             <tr>
             <th scope="col">Customer Name</th>
             <th scope="col">Contact Name</th>
             <th scope="col">Phone Number</th>
             <th scope="col">Email</th>
             <th scope="col">Action Select</th>
             </tr>
             </thead>
          </table>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#contact_table').DataTable({
            "serverside":true,
            "processing": true,
            "scrollX":true,
            "ajax": 'load_table_data',
        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `#example` to your own id i.e `#contact_table`.
You have used `#example` which you don't have, you need to use `#contact_table`

Plus, make sure that the `th` and `td` of the `table` are equal in number, because `DataTables` requires `well organized` tables.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#contact_table').DataTable({
        "serverside":true,
        "processing": true,
        "scrollX":true,
        "ajax": 'load_table_data',
    });
})
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zy6xkqj0/1/)

Comment: thank for response, i have edited my code but it still not working

Comment: did you checked the `fiddle` ? As I mentioned, the table you are loading should be well organized, that is, it should have proper `th` and `td`, they should be equal in number, not mis-match.
Kindly share `table` html that you are loading.